# Django preventing duplicate records while importing csv

Tags: django, csv, duplicates

I am uploading csv file to django model, which is working fine with the below code

```
def upload_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csv_file']:
        myfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename, mode='r'))
        for row in data:
            if row[0] != 'FP_Item':
                post = FP()
                post.FP_Item = row[0]
                post.save()
        messages.success(request, "FP uploaded to Database")
        queryset_list = FP.objects.all()
        context = {'object_list': queryset_list}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

What I need is to prevent duplicates entries to database.  When I see duplicate field, I need to continue without saving with post.save() so I modified my code as per below but still saving even it's duplicate.No errors at code as well.What I am doing false ?

```
for row in data:
    queryset_list = FP.objects.all()
    if row[0] != 'FP_Item':
        if row[0] == queryset_list.filter(FP_Item__contains=row[0]):
            continue
    post = FP()
    post.FP_Item = row[0]
    post.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row[0]` will never be equal to `queryset_list.filter`, which is still a queryset. You can do this:

```
if FP.objects.filter(FP_Item__contains=row[0]):
    continue
```